# Can nautilus show the real file transfer progress?

Tags: nautilus, filesystem, filemanager

When I copy large files to an external drive, although nautilus's progress popup indicates it's finished, the transfer is not actually completed, I need to open terminal and use sync to make sure it is finished, and for large files, sync will take a long time. Is it possible to let the GUI, e.g. nautilus tell me the actual progress.